# Install m2eclipse gives error

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I tried to install via site update using the follwoing url 
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3 -
And getting following error

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.feature,1.3.1.R201102081640
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.gathering,1.3.1.R201102081640
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.recording,1.3.1.R201102081640
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.ui,1.3.1.R201102081640
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.compatibility,1.0.1.v20110204-1323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.proxy,2.0.301.v201101101700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.util,2.1.3.v201012070000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.frameworks,1.1.403.v201012160000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.ui,1.0.3.v201101101700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee,1.1.404.v201102081800
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core,1.2.4.v201102101900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web,1.1.404.v201102030400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jee,1.0.302.v201101122300
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core,1.2.304.v201102160550
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui,1.1.503.v201101262228
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emf,1.2.3.v201012100400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration,1.2.3.v201012020600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore,1.2.5.v201101270100
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ui,1.0.4.v201101101700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.snippets,1.2.2.v201101130441
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.core,1.1.402.v201102031915
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.ui,1.0.502.v201101122002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtd.core,1.1.401.v201101122255
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.core,1.1.404.v201101190004
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.ui,1.0.504.v201101122108
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core,1.1.4.v201102102045
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.core,1.0.3.v201011040143
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.ui,1.0.3.v201011040143
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui,1.1.4.v201102160540
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.core,1.0.304.v201102160550
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.support.jsp,1.0.303.v201012160047
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.ui,1.0.304.v201012160349
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.core,1.1.206.v20110110
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.ui,1.1.207.v20110119
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.504.v201102160550
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui,1.2.3.v201102102045
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation,1.2.201.v201101270100
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.web,1.1.402.v201012160000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.ws.service.policy,1.0.204.v201011011834
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.wsdl,1.2.104.v201012082239
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.wsdl.ui,1.2.304.v201012071645
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.503.v201102102045
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui,1.1.103.v201101122108
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsd.core,1.1.503.v201011121919
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsd.ui,1.2.304.v201101251958
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.feature,1.0.1.R36x_v20110210-4-09oB5865H6L02434
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.web_core.feature,3.2.3.v201102101900-7Q7BG7HFE9Le9HDKz-hZ-Rlojqz-
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature,3.2.3.v201101262333-7F77FJ_C25TkfyypjhqQuxNYsMrJ
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.web_userdoc.feature,3.2.2.v201010211813-2107w31211938
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_core.feature,3.2.3.v201011031800-7B7DFEsF7RZHOaLfS0KpNJ
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature,3.2.3.v201011031800-7C78FPlEdhO_oXWe4k_elbMgT1Lq
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature,1.2.3.v201102160540-7C78FGUF9JgLWNO2UCNqfa
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_core.feature,3.2.3.v20101104-30F8X8s734D3A4C
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_ui.feature,3.2.3.v20101104-7B4FBuAtJb1qEKLnCKHHHI347
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_core.feature,3.2.3.v201102160541-7E7AFI3AJrn5TN32vSJ8nRIWLD7_
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature,3.2.3.v201102160541-7O7CFbWEMf84qYjGDyP3DNEwcgFU
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.ws_core.feature,3.2.3.v201102160541-7L7RFf0FGtGd-nipy6nDoi4852
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.ws_ui.feature,3.2.3.v201102160541-7I78FZIEtEoO2d7AsK6jSNqC-8jj
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature,3.2.3.v201102160550-7C7OFXcF7RZHQKIkMxMsW_
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature,3.2.3.v201102160550-7H7AFUWDxumQJOi9ghcTb5YgkwEZ
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_userdoc.feature,3.2.101.v201102161624-50FXNAkF7B77RBgFFBF
```

Please let us know your comments to resolve.

Comment: 1.4 is the current release are you sure you want 1.3?

Comment: I tried with Helios Service pack1. anyway when i browsed  for m2e for it , i tried with many url via help-> Install software . that ran for installation and got this error. Im not known whether to use latest or 1.3 specific but gave a try newly in helios. One more point to note my system space in installed in dCLoud machine with windows7. please suggest ur ideas.